# OpenLayers with map starting in Australia

Tags: javascript, openlayers

I'm very new to OpenLayers and I'm trying to show a map on my home page, which shows only Australia, and then later add some points on the map.  The important thing right now, is to just open the map to Australia.

I'm using the example found on OpenLayers home page, with:

```
var map = new OpenLayers.Map('map');
var wms = new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS( "OpenLayers WMS",
        "http://vmap0.tiles.osgeo.org/wms/vmap0", {layers: 'basic'} );
....
```

I'm guessing that I have to pass something to the constructor to have it display only a specific region?

Thanks,

Sam

Answer (score 0):

Found this on another stackoverflow question:

```
var bounds = new OpenLayers.Bounds(-125, 25, -65, 50);
var map = new OpenLayers.Map('map', {restrictedExtent: bounds  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Open Layers uses projection to accommodate a 2D map of a 3D world. Projection is a mathematical way of saying that on a 3D sphere (the world) the coordinates x,y are actually x,y somewhere else on a 2D map. In openlayers this involves changing the view, you can use the fromLonLat() method. More information on projection here: https://openlayers.org/en/latest/doc/faq.html

```js
mapOfAustralia = new ol.Map({
  layers: [
    new ol.layer.Tile({
    source: new ol.source.OSM()
  })
  ],
  target: targetElement,
  controls: ol.control.defaults({
  attributionOptions: {
  collapsible: false
  }
  }),
    view: new ol.View({
    center: ol.proj.fromLonLat([133.7751, -23.2744]),
    zoom: 4
  })
});
```